# Meaning of graph in Birch and Swinnerton Dyer conjecture

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, elliptic-curves

The following graph is taken from a Wikipedia article about the Birch and Swinnerton Dyer conjecture

[image]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture

Does $N_p/p$ mean that you take a large number of rational points on an elliptic curve that occur before some value $X$ on the $X$-axis and divide by the largest prime number that occurs before $X$? And can there be millions of rational points in the value of $N_p$? Also does the plot, if it has slope 1 as the conjecture says, mean that if I increase the value of $X$ 10 times the value of $N_p/p$ doubles?

Comment: Welcome! Please do not rely on pictures of text. A graph is fine, but not text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: There is a detailed answer here as to the meaning of Np/p.  https://www.quora.com/What-does-Np-p-mean-in-the-Birch-and-Swinnerton-Dyer-conjecture